# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str (I don't think that should happen)

Tags: python

I decided it would be a cool idea to make a translator to a custom language, so I tried making one. However, I am fairly new to python, and I cannot figure out why it is expecting a string instead of an integer. What I am trying to do is make it so if you enter in a word such as 'bin', it will go to the next consonant/vowel for each, so 'bin' ends up as 'cop' as the next consonant after 'b' is 'c', the next vowel after 'i' is 'o' and the next consonant after 'n' is 'p'.

```
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
translated_word = ''

word_to_translate = input('Enter in the word to translate! ')

for letter in range(len(word_to_translate)):
    new_letter = word_to_translate[letter - 1]
    if new_letter in consonants:
        l = (consonants[:new_letter + 1])
        translated_word = translated_word + str(l)
    elif new_letter in vowels:
        l = (vowels[:new_letter + 1])
        translated_word = translated_word + str(l)

print(translated_word)
```

Comment: `new_letter + 1` is trying to add `1` to a string…

Comment: what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Rethink what you're trying to do there. What is `'a' + 1` supposed to do?

Comment: @deceze it is supposed to make it so a word like 'bin' would become 'cop'. This is because the next consonant after 'b' is 'c', the next vowel after 'i' is 'o' and the next consonant after 'n' is 'p'. The a + 1 is supposed to select the next character in the list after a.

Answer (score 0):

```
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
translated_word = ''

word_to_translate = input('Enter in the word to translate! ')

for i in word_to_translate:
    if i in consonants:
        ind = consonants.index(i)
        translated_word += consonants[ind+1] 
    elif i in vowels:
        ind = vowels.index(i)
        translated_word += vowels[ind+1]
print (translated_word)
```